# CreateComputeShader returns E_INVALIDARG when using doubles

Tags: c++, gpgpu, direct3d, hlsl, direct3d11

I need double precision for some GPGPU calculations using DirectCompute.  When I make everything a float, the shader compiles and runs just fine.  However, when I try to use doubles anywhere in my shader, it will compile, but calling `ID3D11Device::CreateComputeShader()` at runtime fails with `E_INVALIDARG`.  The C++ side code is exactly the same, mind you, I've just changed a few variables in the shader to double.

When I call `ID3D11Device::CheckFeatureSupport()` with `D3D11_FEATURE_DOUBLES`, it reports that doubles are supported on my adapter, which is an AMD Radeon R9 270x.  According to a couple of Google searches, AMD cards are actually great at double precision calculations - IE, my card can use doubles, but DirectX doesn't seem to want to let me do that.

I figured that maybe DirectCompute doesn't have that ability (which would be weird, since a lot of scientific GPGPU processes need doubles), so I tried using a pixel shader instead.  The same thing happens.

Is this a driver bug, or is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: I just searched for the latest Catalyst driver, and apparently I'm behind a couple versions.  This is interesting, considering I've gone to the control center and checked for updates several times recently.  I'm going to update and see what happens.

EDIT2: The update had no effect.  Either I'm doing something wrong, or DirectX has a bug of sorts.

Comment: What feature level did you create your device at?

Comment: @AdamMiles I passed it nullptr for feature levels so that it defaults to whatever's available

Comment: @AdamMiles However, it must be using version 11.0 because 11.1 doesn't work on my environment.

Comment: Which operations on doubles in particular are you using? Are you dividing? The ``D3D11_FEATURE_DOUBLES`` covers the basic double operations, but your shader may require you to check ``D3D11_FEATURE_D3D11_OPTIONS`` for ``D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ExtendedDoublesShaderInstructions`` instead which covers FMA, DDIV, and DRCP as well.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Ah, okay.  That's set to false.  So in that case, what _can_ I do, and what should I do to get around what I _can't_ do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic double-precision shader model 5.0 support as indicated by `D3D11_FEATURE_DOUBLES` only includes support for the following operations:

- `dadd` - Addition/Negation/Subtraction
- `deq`, `dge`, `dlt`, `dne`- Comparison
- `dmax` - Max
- `dmin` - Min
- `dmov`, `dmovc` - Moves
- `dmul` - Multiply
- `dtof`, `ftod` - Conversion double <-> float

You need to check `D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ExtendedDoublesShaderInstructions` which includes all the ones above plus:

- `dfma` - Fused multiply-add
- `ddiv` - Division
- `drcp` - Reciprocal

[Shader Model 5 Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/shader-model-5-assembly--directx-hlsl-)

**RE: DirectX 11.1**

`D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ExtendedDoublesShaderInstructions` is part of the DirectX 11.1 API and is a hardware feature that requires WDDM 1.2 drivers. Therefore, as per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/platform-update-for-windows-7), even with the DirectX 11.1 runtime installed on Windows 7 via [KB2670838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2670838) this hardware feature requires Windows 8 or later to be TRUE.

[DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/)
[DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-11-1-and-windows-7/)

Comment: I selected this as the correct answer, since it's likely the answer in most cases, but I don't have dfma, ddiv, or drcp in my code anywhere.  I am multiplying a double by a uint, though, and getting rid of that line allows the shader to be bound.

Comment: Look at the assembly generated by the HLSL compiler for the failed shaders for these instructions. More than likely, your shader got 'optimized' to use the extra instructions. Ideally there'd be a way to keep the HLSL compiler from using them, but I don't see such a switch in the tool.

Comment: That turned out to be it.  Since there's no inline assembly in HLSL, DirectCompute is too much of a burden for this kind of project.  I tried using doubles in OpenCL, and it seems to allow them indiscriminately.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn If it’s part of 11.1, why does the runtime return D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ExtendedDoublesShaderInstructions = TRUE on FL 11.0 GPUs such as GeForce 920M? Shaders don't actually work, getting that E_INVALIDARG. Using Windows 10.

Comment: There's a distinction between "11.1" the software API and "11.1" the Direct3D Hardware Feature Level. You will get ``E_INVALIDARG`` for the query about ``D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS`` on Windows Vista with DirectX 11.0 or Windows 7 without the DirectX 11.1 Runtime. On Windows 7, however, there' s no new *driver interface* so the value ``D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ExtendedDoublesShaderInstructions`` will always be FALSE. On Windows 10, it's up to the driver to report TRUE or FALSE. Also, these instructions are always optional even with Feature Level 11.1, 12.0, and 12.1